# Enable QT to show minimize, maximize and close buttons

Tags: android, qt

I am developing an android app using QT for android. However, I find out that Qt hide minimize, maximize and close buttons when I deploy my app into the phone. Those buttons are missing, which are different from the desktop PC version. Now, it is not a window format, how can I make it like the normal window shown in Window on the mobile?

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    /*setWindowFlags(Qt::Window
    | Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint
    | Qt::WindowMaximizeButtonHint
    | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint);*/
    ui->setupUi(this);

    setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint);
}
```

Comment: What behavior do you expect from "maximize" button on Android? Does mobile versions of Android support multiapplication/multiwindow GUI?

Comment: Sorry, I am a newbie for using android.

Comment: it doesn't matter. Could you show any app for Android that has "Maximize" or other similar buttons? It is not clear, what you expect to get.

Comment: Thanks for reminding. It seems the case having "Maximizing" button doesn't exist. I will consider to use other ways.

Comment: Much better way is to use `QtQuick`/`QML` that are designed for modern mobile platforms. Widgets are not.